# Is there a way to tell if the replace is visible in the search box?

Tags: ace-editor

Is there a way to tell if the replace field in a search box is visible?

I'm currently using the following to check if the search box is visible:

```
var isVisible = editor.searchBox.element.style.display != "none";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a flag for it:

```
var isSearchVisible = editor.searchBox.element.style.display != "none";
var isReplace = editor.searchBox.isReplace;

var isReplaceVisible = isReplace && isSearchVisible;
```